# Updating array values (Appcelerator Titanium Mobile)

Tags: arrays, titanium

I'm using both the 1.5.1 and 1.6.0 to test my apps on my OS X.

I'm trying to update some values in this array:

```
var myTab = [
{title:'foo1',value:'bar1'},
{title:'foo2',value:'bar2'}
];
```

If I update a value field in this array, it doesn't do it (which isn't normal):

```
Titanium.API.info('Before :' + myTab[0].value);
myTab[0].value = 'updated!';
Titanium.API.info('After :' + myTab[0].value);
```

It displays 'bar1' instead of 'updated!'.
What I tried next is to put the tab as a property list:

```
Titanium.App.Properties.setList('propTab',myTab);
```

And then, I tried to do the same thing:

```
Titanium.API.info('Before :' + Titanium.App.Properties.getList('propTab')[0].value);
Titanium.App.Properties.getList('propTab')[0].value = 'updated!';
Titanium.API.info('After :' +  Titanium.App.Properties.getList('propTab')[0].value[0].value);
```

Same result: It displays 'bar1' instead of 'updated!'.

Is there another solution?

Thank you,

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've run into this sort of behavior before.  While I never ascertained the cause, I found a workaround: you need to set `myTab[0]` to a value, and not `myTab[0].value` to a value.  So, thus:

```
myTab[0] = {title: myTab[0].title, value: "updated!"};
```

Why, I do not know... I should probably figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention it as an array element then it should work. For e.g., in your case you may modify as foolows

```
myTab[0]['value'] = 'updated!';
```